# Sending large JSON to ASP.NET Core server make Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-core

I'm trying to request with large javascript object like

```
var objectArr = [
    {
        NAME: "foo",
        GROUP: "bar",
        PHONE_NUM: "1234567890"
    },
    ...
];
objectArr.length > 250
```

Actually I don't think it is large, but when I send this object to server, the server response with `500 Internal Server Error`. 
When I send object with `length < 250`, there is no error.
Following is action method of controller, request and response of it. (only selected information)

**Model**

```
public class Info 
{
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string GROUP{ get; set; }
    public string PHONE_NUM { get; set; }
}
```

**Action Method**

```
public JsonResult ReceiveJSON(List<Info> objectArr)
{
    // handling objectArr --------------- (1)
    return null;
}
```

**Request Header**

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:77898
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
```

**Response Header**

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

The real problem is that when I check debug point at `(1)` in `ReceiveJSON` action method and send Json object to it from browser with POST method, **the debugger do not stop** at `(1)` and response `500 Internal Server Error`. I think it is not a response error but some issue in middleware for request.

Is there any way to resolve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes maxJsonLength work for asp.net freamwork, not nessesary in .net core.
An HTTP response has no size limit. JSON is already come as an HTTP response. but has no size limit either.

There might be problem if the object parsed from JSON response consumes too much memory. It'll crash the browser. So it's better you test with different data sizes and check whether your app works correctly.

try Lazy-loading may be solve for this.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Core and (as I know) I can not handle web.config directly. Is there another way?

Comment: thank you for your answer! I think the question not enough to understanding. So I revised it.